# Rails 6 ActionCable/Redis production configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I'm currently integrating Stimulus Reflex and Cable Ready in my application and want to deploy it to my production server. The guides on how to deploy ActionCable to production seem very outdated, they're mostly written for Rails 5.

I found different tutorials on this topic, but most of them for Rails 4/5.
Regarding the `cable.yml` configuration file: If I install redis on my webserver, does the production url have to point to localhost or to my domain?

```
url: redis://localhost:6379/1

url: redis://redis.mydomain.com:6379/1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## config/environments/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/0") }
end
```

## config/cable.yml

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/0") %>
  channel_prefix: app_production
```

For better understanding you can follow this site.
https://hixonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorials/ruby-on-rails-redis-installation-and-configuration/

Comment: Don't you mean `url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") %>` ?

Comment: @jbw By doing `<%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/0") %>`, if REDIS_URL isn't defined, it will use `redis://localhost:6379/0`